# How to implement remove_noise on PocketSphinx android?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

I have implement the speech recognition using PocketSphinx in my android application, everything works fine except the recognizer is too sensitive. It made my application result (speech-to-text) not working properly.

I have already change the threshold until the lowest I can get, which is 1f.

I used English, and limited library with certain grammar, and I make my own dictionary using the Sphinx Knowledge Base Tool.

Even though I used the acoustic model en-us-ptm from the demo of cmuSphinx.

**I have done some research that Sphinx have remove_noise function, but I can seems to find it. 
or is there any other way to make the pocketsphinx recognizer better ?**

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest pocketsphinx has internal noise reduction module. There is no easy way you can remove/reduce noise as they would have done if there is such.

External noise reduction degrades speech recognition accuracy. Make sure you're using updated version of the library and [language model](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Acoustic%20Model/en-us.tar.gz/download)

See more about increasing the accuracy of the recognizer: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor

Comment: hi, thankyou for your respond, I used the language model from the demo given, and I tried to understand that link you gave, but wht I understand is that the pocketsphinx in android can not be trained? am I wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Sphinx comes with finest acoustic models but if you want to specialize for small vocabulary application you can perform [Training Acoustic Model](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam) which I don't recommend you to try.

The best way is to do some simple acoustic model adaptation to improve speech recognition . Check out this [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt).